# App works on iphone ipad simulator but not ipad device: Black screen and then goes out

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ipad-2

I've an iPhone app that Works perfectly on iPhone simulator/device.

It runs in iPhone resolution and iPhone 2X resolution (i.e. I didn't add any root viewcontrollers for iPad).

The problem is the application works fine on iPad simulator, but when open in iPad device, **the screen goes black then the application exit.**

What do you think the cause of this problem?

Comment: The simulator is case insensitive. The devices are case sensitive. Could that lead to your problem?

Comment: But it works well on iPhone/iPod devices

Comment: I was just guessing. Do you load different pictures of the iPad? Have you tried on retina and old iPhone/iPod?

Comment: It is the exactly the same app, I don't check for iPad for any part of the code. It worked good for iPhone (Retina) simulator. I don't know how to add old simulators. `Please note that, the simulator states that it is an iOS Simulator - iPad / iOS 4.3.2 (8H7) but the device is iPad 2 GSM (4.3.3), does this matter?`

Comment: I would put in some debug points in the code after you load your initial screen to see why it doesn't come on screen. Then run it in debug mode on the iPad from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem after upgrading an iPhone app to be a universal app. The app worked in the iPhone and iPad simulators, but when I tried running it on my iPhone, I got the same black screen and app exit as you did.

The fix was to make sure that the 'Main Storyboard' was set properly on the Project Targets Summary page for both the iPod/iPhone section and the iPad section. For some reason, my iPod/iPhone Main Storyboard was blank. After fixing it, my app started working.